# I'm making a PEMDAS solver and don't know what to write

Tags: python, math, algebra

I am trying to make a [PEMDAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) solver where the user types in a PEMDAS problem.  For example, they would type in 4(4 + 2) - 5 and the program would solve it for them.  is there any code that would make python solve the input that the user enters.

something like:

```
problem = input()
solve(problem)
print(problem)
```

I obviously know that "solve" is not a real command in python.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It's usually a good idea to include in your post what you've tried so far so that we can help you better. Don't make an "I can has teh codez?" post.

Comment: Python's built-in math solver does this. So you would just need to `eval` (veal(raw_input("Enter the expression you would like solved: "))) the user's input. That being said, it's usually a bad idea to simply `eval` user input.

So you might be better off parsing the string into a tree. But without knowing the scope of your problem, this is pretty difficult to tackle

Comment: This is an extremely vague question. AFAIK there's nothing built into Python to handle this kind of thing, a good place to start would be to parse the input into [RPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) and have some sort of lookup for operator strings (eg "+") that takes your operands and plugs them into a lambda or something.